# How can I use asyncio.sleep in python-bonobo

Tags: python, bonobo-etl

I want to transmit data with a slow web-service; but all the same I want to avoid busy waiting.
Is there a way that I can do asyncio.sleep in the ETL graph? do other async/await commands can be used in bonobo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no active work on `bonobo` library, and the `async` features of it does not actually work. So, there is no way of using `asyncio.sleep` in current `bonobo` version.